# Trigger a HTTP error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-403, http-error

I'm trying to call a custom instance of a 403 HTTP error in Rails but I can't seem to figure out how to do this...

I have several user authentication roles and basically if a role tries to browse to an area that it is not authorised to visit I want to display a 403 instead of just redirecting the user.

How do I do this?

Comment: I think the accepted answer should be changed -- this one is a better solution, since it's the correct error code as well as a better presentation to the end user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130191/how-to-return-correct-http-error-codes-from-ruby-on-rails-application

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In your controller code add the following line:

```
render :status => :forbidden, :text => "Forbidden fruit"
```

Refer to [this page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render#254-List-of-status-codes-and-their-symbols) for http code to symbol mapping.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks heaps... FYI you're missing a comma after :forbidden

Comment: Thanks I have updated the answer and added a reference to http code to ruby symbol list.

Comment: The old url to the code mapping is gone. I updated it to point to apidock instead. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render#254-List-of-status-codes-and-their-symbols

Comment: The `:text` will need to become `:plain` in newer versions of Rails.

Answer (score 5):

Just for posterity: I think [return 403.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130191/how-to-return-correct-http-error-codes-from-ruby-on-rails-application) is a nicer solution, because it generates a standard page, just like the 404. The above solution only displays the text given. And because someone in good practice can only go to a forbidden page by typing or clicking a link outside the web app, a standard error page is the way to go.