# How to return correct HTTP error codes from Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I have RoR 3.0 web application which is acting as an OAuth API provider. Now, in API I'd like to return correct HTTP error codes to the API consumer. How do I do this?

Here is example:

```
def destroy_oauth
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if(!@item.nil? && @item.user_id == current_user.id)
        @item.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
                format.js
                format.xml
        end
    else
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Forbidden')
    end
end
```

So, in case of error I'm trying to return Forbidden 403 code. Still, when running this I'm getting always 404 Not Found returned. How do I return the correct code?

Or is this somehow webserver configurable thing?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should render page with correct status.

```
render(:file => File.join(Rails.root, 'public/403.html'), :status => 403, :layout => false)
```

Comment: Should I do this also for OAuth API xml responses?

Comment: As a side-note here, specifying the `.html` extension like this is deprecated (see discussion at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7288), so we should use `render(:file => File.join(Rails.root, 'public/403'), :formats => [:html], :status => 403, :layout => false)` (note the way I've specified the format).

Comment: ... or even `render(:file => Rails.root.join('public', '403'), :formats => [:html], :status => 403, :layout => false)`.

Answer (score 67):

When you're just giving a status code and there is no body, a convenient way is

```
head 403
```

This method also accepts the symbolic names for status codes, such as

```
head :forbidden
```

Comment: Oh, that could be what I need. Will try.

Answer (score 18):

According to [ActionController::Head docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html) just use this pattern in actions

```
  return head([status]) if/unless [some condition here]
```

Example:

```
  return head(:gone) if @record.deleted?
  return head(:forbidden) unless @user.owns?(@record)
```

`return` is used to make sure that no remaining code in the action will be run.

Comment: Is there any difference between `head :forbidden && return` and `return head :forbidden`? In my testing,I had to use the latter to return early from controller. With the former, I got 204 returned.

Comment: @wlnirvana Ahhhh that's why I was getting a 204 No Content returned, I couldn't understand why `head :forbidden && return` didn't work, while `head(:forbidden) && return` did

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two problems here: first is that your `@item = Item.find(params[:id])` line is raising 404 and execution never gets to where intended (`if` statement). Second is that you are raising exceptions and never catch them. Try:

```
def destroy_oauth
   begin
     @item = Item.find(params[:id])
     if(!@item.nil? && @item.user_id == current_user.id)
       @item.destroy
       respond_to do |format|
          format.js
          format.xml
       end
     else
       raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Forbidden')
     end
   rescue ActiveRecord::ResourceNotFound
     redirect_to :action => 'not_found', :status => 404 # do whatever you want here
   rescue ActionController::RoutingError
     redirect_to :action => 'forbidden', :status => 403 # do whatever you want here
   end
 end
```

Something along those lines, but you also mentioned that you are building the API, so when you are rescuing the error, you may want to render `xml` error info. Something like:

```
# in application_controller.rb
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_forbidden_error

private

def render_forbidden_error(e)
  render :status => e.status, :xml => e
end
```

Good luck. Udachi.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can use

```
:status =>500
```

But, In default Rails take care of the error type rendering itself.

Errors default pages are in the public directory. 500.html,404.html etc..

[For more information on `:status` , how to use it click here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option)

Comment: Yes, I probably have to play with these :status parameters. Thanks!

Comment: Well, this is true. However, if I am working on an API in rails, I would need to explicitly mentioned the status code